# Python. PyTelegramBotAPI, не отправляется сообщение пользователю

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types

#import config

#bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)


token = "5@#%^*&((*&^$#"
bot = TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Магазин гемов")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Открыть бесплатный ящик")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        text=" Привет, это бот с продажей гемов для игры Brawl Stars.\n"
             "Но вы так же можете испытать удачу и открыть бесплатный ящик с гемами".format(message.from_user),
        reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "Открыть бесплатный ящик":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        photo = open("C:/Users/miroa/Documents/rght/bot_leon/free_gems.jpg", "rb")
        my = types.KeyboardButton("Забрать")
        markup.add(my)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo,
                       caption='Поздравляем, вы выиграли 550 \nЖми кнопку «Забрать»',
                       reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Магазин гемов":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        gem80 = types.KeyboardButton("80-99₽")
        gem170 = types.KeyboardButton("170-199₽")
        gem360 = types.KeyboardButton("360-379₽")
        gem530 = types.KeyboardButton("530-529₽")
        markup.add(gem80, gem170, gem360, gem530)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         text="Ты попал в наш магазин, выбери товар который хочешь купить ",
                         reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(gem80, tag)
    
    elif message.text == "Забрать":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        global photo1
        photo1 = open("C:/Users/miroa/Documents/rght/bot_leon/teg_bw.jpg", "rb")
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo1,
                       caption="Введите тэг своего аккаунта Brawl Stars\n"
                               "Пример: #VLLQ9GOR\n"
                               "Узнать свой тэг вы можете в профиле игры, пример на фото:",
                       reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, true_or_false)
################################################################################################
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def tag(message: types.Message):
    photo2 = open("C:/Users/miroa/Documents/rght/bot_leon/teg_bw.jpg", "rb")
    if message.text == "80-99₽":
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo2,
                       caption="Введите тэг своего аккаунта Brawl Stars\n"
                               "Пример: #VLLQ9GOR\n"
                               "Узнать свой тэг вы можете в профиле игры, пример на фото:")#вот что не отправляется
################################################################################################
#blablabla
bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае у тебя 2 `message_handler` с одинаковым фильром апдейта, и в итоге любое текстовое сообщение будет обрабатываться всегда первым, а до второго не дойдет, используй более точные фильтры, например по точному совпадению текста, это атрибут `text` в `messsage_handler`